# Determine orthotropic axes of Stiffness Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, tensor-decomposition

Consider a fourth oder stiffness tensor $\mathbb{C}$. The components $C_{ijkl}$ are given with respect to a global coordinate system. Is there a way to determine the orthotropic axes from this representation?

In Mandel-Kelvin-Notation we can express the tensor as $6\times6$-Matrix
\begin{equation} 
\mathbb{C} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{C}_{11} & \tilde{C}_{12} & \tilde{C}_{13} & \tilde{C}_{14} & \tilde{C}_{15} & \tilde{C}_{16} \\
 & \tilde{C}_{22} & \tilde{C}_{23} & \tilde{C}_{24} & \tilde{C}_{25} & \tilde{C}_{26} \\
& & \tilde{C}_{33} & \tilde{C}_{34} & \tilde{C}_{35} & \tilde{C}_{36}  \\
& & & \tilde{C}_{44} & \tilde{C}_{45} & \tilde{C}_{46} \\
&  \text{sym} & & & \tilde{C}_{55} & \tilde{C}_{56} \\
 & & & & & \tilde{C}_{66} 
\end{pmatrix} \tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_\alpha \otimes \tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_\beta =
 \begin{pmatrix} 
C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& C_{22} & C_{23}  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 & & C_{33} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& & & C_{44} & 0 & 0 \\
& \text{sym} & & & C_{55}  & 0 \\
& & & & & C_{66} \\
\end{pmatrix} \boldsymbol{B}_\alpha \otimes \boldsymbol{B}_\beta
\end{equation}
with the global basis $\lbrace \tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_\alpha \rbrace$:
\begin{align}
\tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_1 &= \boldsymbol{e}_x \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_x \\
\tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_2 &= \boldsymbol{e}_y \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_y \\
\tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_3 &= \boldsymbol{e}_z \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_z \\
\tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_4 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\boldsymbol{e}_y \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_z + \boldsymbol{e}_z \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_y \right) \\
\tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_5 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\boldsymbol{e}_x \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_z + \boldsymbol{e}_z \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_x \right) \\
\tilde{\boldsymbol{B}}_6 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\boldsymbol{e}_x \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_y + \boldsymbol{e}_y \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_x \right) \\
\end{align}

and the orthotropic basis $\lbrace \boldsymbol{B}_\alpha \rbrace$

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{B}_1 &= \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1 \\
\boldsymbol{B}_2 &= \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_2 \\
\boldsymbol{B}_3 &= \boldsymbol{e}_3 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_3 \\
\boldsymbol{B}_4 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_3 + \boldsymbol{e}_3 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_2 \right) \\
\boldsymbol{B}_5 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_3 + \boldsymbol{e}_3 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1 \right) \\
\boldsymbol{B}_6 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_2 + \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1 \right) \\
\end{align}

The orthonormal-system $\lbrace \boldsymbol{e}_1, \boldsymbol{e}_2, \boldsymbol{e}_3 \rbrace$ would represent the orthtropic axes, I am looking for.

Help would be really much appreciated. TIA